# python manage.py migrate KeyError: 255

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-manage.py

Server environment configuration

```
Ubuntu 14
Django 1.11.3
Python 3.6.1
MySql 8.0.1
```

When I execute `python manage.py dbshell` command everything works ok.

But when I execute `python manage.py migrate` command, I get a `KeyError: 255`.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 110, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 282, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 274, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 90, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 706, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 931, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1269, in _get_server_information
    self.server_charset = charset_by_id(lang).name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/charset.py", line 38, in by_id
    return self._by_id[id]
KeyError: 255
```

module：

```
from django.db import models

class UserInfo (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    tel  = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Comment: you have to post your models code

Comment: check your connection to db. As far as I see you have a problem with connection module.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
manage.py makemigrations
```

then

```
manage.py migrate
```

You need to give the modal's code by the way.